# "Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:1140: unexpected string constant" when using MICE for imputation

Tags: r, r-mice

I am very new to coding so this may be an easy fix but I cannot understand why I keep getting this error. I am trying to impute missing data for a dataframe I have created from Excel using MICE. I have found online that use of spaces in column names and use of certain characters or numbers can use str2lang(X) error codes but I have renamed all my columns to use solely letters with no spaces so I don't know why I keep getting this code. Does anyone have any ideas? I'd be very grateful!

The code I am using to attempt multiple imputation is:
`library(mice) init = mice(df, maxit=0)  meth = init$method predM = init$predictorMatrix`

(df being a large dataframe with 65 columns (could the size be causing an issue?))

It gives the error code as follows:
Error in str2lang(x) : :1:1154: unexpected string constant
1:
VariableOne+VariableTwo+VariableThree+VariableFour+VariableFive

Comment: Hi Verity. Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's very difficult to say what might be wrong with your code and suggest fixes if we don't know what your code _is_. Would you be able to edit your question to include the code that produced the error? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Allan, I have included the code but the it seems to work for other datasets, so I am not sure why it doesn't with mine, and that led me to believe it may be due to the naming of columns, but that was a dead end. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thank you!!

Comment: Would you be able to add the column names to your question too, just in case? If you type `dput(names(df))` into the console, then copy-paste that into your question, we could probably get a solution from there.

Comment: @VerityBlack “ it seems to work for other datasets” — that’s why it’s important to also include the *relevant data*, not just the code, when posting a reproducible example. See [mcve].

Comment: I had something very much like this, and I _think_ it was due to my original column variable naming (as per your reply). In my case I had a leading number, describing the questionnaire item number, followed by characters. 

Things cleared up after I grossly simplified the column naming, to an 'a1, b2' style format.

Comment: Just checked - my similar error message was
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:2: unexpected symbol
1: 1memory
     ^

Following Konrad's request above would be the best way for you to proceed. Sometimes creating something you can post reveals the solution without posting it (as it were).

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg